# I want to update a file(textfile) when user changes the data in JTable on clicking the update button?

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtable

I have Jtable with column names "item","price","quantity"and "reorder" the requirement is such that when user make the changes in the any of these above fields and clicks the update button and the updated data should be write in to the text file (I have created a textfile "MyFile.txt"). How?

Comment: well, I would start with re-reading my basic tutorial ;-) Then try break up the requirement into different blocks (f.i. writing to a file, listen to changes in the table, listen to clicking of the button) that can be solved one after the other. At last combine the blocks. When you stumble into a concrete problem during one of the blocks or at the end, come back and ask a concrete question :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a java.io.FileWriter to append data to a file.

```
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("filename",true);
```

The second parameter specifies whether the file is to be opened in 'append' mode.